# How to share data or message on twitter using wpf application?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having trouble implementing share data on Twitter. Does anyone
  have sample code for share data using wpf application??

This is the code followed in WPF:

Here, I am getting HttpRequest error.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var oauth_consumer_key = "XXX";
        var oauth_consumer_secret = "YYY";

        if(Request["oauth_token"] == null)
        {
            OAuthTokenResponse reqToken = OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken(
                oauth_consumer_key,
                oauth_consumer_secret,
                Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);

            NavigationService nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
            nav.Navigate(string.Format("http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token={0}", reqToken.Token, UriKind.Relative));               
        }
        else
        {
            string requestToken = Request["oauth_token"].ToString();
            string pin = Request["oauth_verifier"].ToString();
            var tokens = OAuthUtility.GetAccessToken(
                oauth_consumer_key,
                oauth_consumer_secret,
                requestToken,
                pin);

            OAuthTokens accesstoken = new OAuthTokens()
            {
                AccessToken = tokens.Token,
                AccessTokenSecret = tokens.TokenSecret,
                ConsumerKey = oauth_consumer_key,
                ConsumerSecret = oauth_consumer_secret
            };

            TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> response = TwitterStatus.Update(
                accesstoken,
                "Testing!! It works (hopefully).");

            if (response.Result == RequestResult.Success)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("we did it!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("it's all bad.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am searching in Net..But I didn't get any idea..

Comment: Have you looked at libraries such as `tweetsharp`. Seems to me this is not a question about WPF specifically but about how to integrate twitter into a .net app. Unless you do know how to do that and are asking about wpf nindings etc in which case you need to edit your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This video is about WebFormApplication asp.net C#.
I hope you get an idea.

First watch the video and understand the concepts.

Video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGEA1sgMMqU

Source COde:

http://www.markhagan.me/Samples/Grant-Access-And-Tweet-As-Twitter-User-ASPNet

Also,You can download the source code from that video (see the link below the video)

Regards

Comment: but don't forget to download twitterizer... it's also mentioned in the video.

Comment: You're welcome...
Btw if you need it for facebook, there is also a useful video about that.
facebook API.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IsO0G-8idyo

Good luck!

Comment: Ok, but If we don't see the code or you don't give more information we can't help you to solve it :(

Comment: try this way for the redirect URL may be it works : or google more about WPF application URL:

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("your Url");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();